# Error installing TensorFlow-experimental on MacOS - curl: (60) SSL certificate

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, tensorflow

When it is being installed Tensorflow-experimental on mac machine for running tensorflow on iOS project, then facing the following problem:

command on terminal: pod install

```
[!] Error installing TensorFlow-experimental
[!] /Users/moniruzzaman/anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/q0/_w6_j9pn3m17k569mj3l1h1r0000gn/T/d20180102-31575-100f04w/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/2cf20b661cbb3374/TensorFlow-experimental-1.1.1.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To turn off SSL verification the following command works:

**echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc**

and then install pod for tensorflow experimental in mac:

**pod install**